# Magento 2: How to add date filter to new product widget

Tags: magento2, widget, new-products

I am using new product `widget` in my custom phtml template. It is showing the newly products.  but i want to add the date filter to this products. How can i do it. Any help appreciated.

template file code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget")->setDisplayType("new_products")->setProductsCount("20")->setTemplate("product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

I have added from and To date fields in `product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml` template but I don't know how to pass this dates to function and get filtered results. Thanks in advance. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> getLayout()->createBlock("Kblikruta\Productslider\Block\Index")->setData('key',
>   'new')->setData('title', 'NEW ARRIVE')->setData('customtext',
>   'lorem')->setTemplate("Kblikruta_Productslider::productslider_grid.phtml")->toHtml();
>   ?>

set attribute using `setData('variablename','value');`

get data in you phtml file using `$block->getVariablename();`